# confidence regino in matlab polyval

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I need to understand how one can calculate the confidence interval for linear regression. The values I got myself is different from the one with Matlab. So, I've been trying to understand how it is done in Matlab. In polyval.m, I don't understand the part of the code below. It seems E is equivalent to [E,R] = qr(V,0). But not sure what it is exactly.
My questions are:

1. How is `[E,R] = qr(V,0) different from [Q,R]=qr(V);`
2. How can `E(=V/R)` be used to calculate the confidence interval (delta below)?

   % S is a structure containing three elements: the triangular factor of the Vandermonde matrix for the original X, the degrees of freedom, and the norm of the residuals.

   E = V/R;

   ```
   e = sqrt(1+sum(E.*E,2));
   ```

   ...

   delta = normr/sqrt(df)*e;

Thanks a lot!

Daisuke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discuss this at some length in my [optimization tips and tricks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8553-optimization-tips-and-tricks) doc.

As for the difference in qr(V,0) to qr(V), that is what is called an economy qr. Read the help docs for qr.

Comment: Your document is very helpful. Thanks!